# Angular $digest() issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

I have a button that toggles a scope variable between true and false:

Template:

```
 <button ng-click="blockToggle();">Toggle</button>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.block=false;
    $scope.blockToggle = function(){
      //console.log('block toggle is being triggered');
      if ($scope.block == false){
        $scope.block = true;
      } else{
        $scope.block = false;
      }
    }
```

In the controller I also have a function called by an interval of 200ms:

```
$scope.scaleHeader = function(){
  console.log('_________'+$scope.block);
  if($scope.block == false){
    console.log('scaling');
    var colNumber = document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader')[0].getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].getElementsByTagName('TH');
    for (i = 0; i < colNumber.length; i++) { 
      var newColSize = document.getElementById(i).getBoundingClientRect().width;
      document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader')[0].getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].getElementsByTagName('TH')[i].style.minWidth = newColSize +"px";
      document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader')[0].getElementsByTagName('TR')[1].getElementsByTagName('TD')[i].style.minWidth = newColSize +"px";    
    }
  }
}
$interval( function(){ $scope.scaleHeader(); }, 200);
```

The scaleHeadar Function that is called by interval should only run passed the if condition if the scope variable "block" is false. This would give a console log of "____false" and another saying "scaling".

The problem is that when scope.block is set to True the scaleHeader function still goes through the if condition which should not happen.

When block set to false I would expect a console log of "____true" and that is it. What I get instead is the following console log:

```
_____true
_____false
scaling
```

Don't understand how that "____false" log can appear in between. Maybe something to do with $digest()?

Apologies for possible incorrect title or lack of ability to express the issue!

Comment: 200ms is a **very** short amount of time. What you're seeing is a typical race condition. The time between you pressing down on the mouse button then lifting up to send the *click* event is probably longer than 200ms

Comment: Also, you know `$interval` continuously runs the function every 200ms, right? There's nothing in your code that suggests it should stop running so your console output looks like what I would expect.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. To run scaleHeader every 200ms as long as scope.block == false. I get the same proplem at 4000ms

Comment: Are you sure $scope.block not set to true in between the interval ? Also i will suggest using $watch instead of interval just to check if $scope.block changed.

Comment: No, it is only toggled between true and false on mouse click. The function scaleHeader runs every 200ms regardlessly of $scope.block value. But it should only run the code inside the if condition if $scope.block is false. For some reason when is set to true after first call to scaleHeader the $scope.block becomes false again just as the log shows.

Comment: @AjinderSingh If I use $watch the function would only run once each time block value is toggled. This is not what I want. I want the function to run every 200ms but only execute part of the code(the part inside the if condition) when scope.block == false

Comment: Weird ! trying putting a debugger inside scaleHeader function and check what happening

Comment: @AlExTsm - Yes , exactly . $watch will run only when block value toggle So put the same check when scope.block == false inside $watch block. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I did as u said but I still get the same outcome!

Comment: try using $scope.block = {value: false} i had similar issues when  using directives that $scope was not updating since the $digest cycle wasnt through...

Comment: @stack91 Same result...